# Tracking number of expressions matched before .ToListing an EF Linq Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Say I am in the select statement of a query:

```
context.Orders.Where(expr).Select(o => new OrderInfo{ ... }).ToList();
```

And I have a list of expressions ( a subset of what is expressed in `expr` ), not all which will be fulfilled ( the idea being they were all the ones added under the `OrElse` condition ):

```
List<Expression<Func<Order, bool>>> exprAppliedList;
```

You could imagine them like this:

```
o => o.BillingFirstName == xStr,
o => o.BillingLastName == xStr,
o => o.ShippingFirstName == xStr,
o => o.ShippingLastName == xStr,

o => o.BillingFirstName == yStr,
o => o.BillingLastName == yStr,
o => o.ShippingFirstName == yStr,
o => o.ShippingLastName == yStr,
```

The trick is, before I .ToList() it, I would like to somehow index *how many*, of the or Expressions I matched on that singular order.
If I type in "John" and someone has `BillingFirstName = "John" BillingLastName = "John", ShippingFirstName = "John", and ShippingLastName = "John"` I could assign him something like `SearchValue = 4`,

I have a lot of reasons for wanting to do this before .ToList(), one being I simply don't actually need those fields other than by filtering.  Another is that I would have to generate a set of different expressions if I wanted to compare it after the fact since they would be of type `List<Expression<Func<OrderInfo, bool>>>` instead.

I realize that EF Linq won't accept any nonsense, custom functions or even a lot of extension methods.  But this is already a list of lambda expressions, which seems to be what Linq eats for breakfast.

I do think I could probably do it after ToList()ing , and perhaps everyone will just say that is what I should do.. But I am also curious if it is possible, because I am a curious guy.. And I think it could be useful in a lot of scenarios.

I tried something wacky like:

```
context.Orders.Where(expr).Select(o => new OrderInfo
{ 
  ... 
  SearchValue = ExpressionMatchList.Any() 
     ? ExpressionMatchList.Count(e => e.Compile().Invoke(o)) 
     : 0,
}).ToList();
```

but then Linq exploded at some sub-dungeon layer.  The most meaningful error seemed to say something like

```
'Unable to process the type '.....[Order].....', because it has no known mapping to the value layer.

> StackTrace: at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NewArrayInitTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
> parent, NewArrayExpression linq)
```

Anyway...  I appreciate your thoughts and consideration on this, even if it turns out to be a totally whack job idea..

Comment: You can't do that. An IQueryable is just a query. Methods like `ToArray()`, `ToList()` or `Count()` tell EF to convert that query to SQL and execute it. Until the SQL statement is executed you can't know if there will be any results. If you want to know the count in advance you'll have to use `.Count()`

Comment: `but then Linq exploded at some sub-dungeon layer.` no, that's the expected behaviour. An IQueryable is a representation of a query. It isn't executed itself. It's passed to a provider for execution. That provider will convert the IQueryable<T> to a query that can be executed against a data source and run *that*. What that error says is that you added code to that query that just can't be converted to SQL

Comment: Yeah i do have awareness that Linq is only writing the query until I .ToList(), I suppose I have to ask the question whether what I want done can be done in SQL first, which seems less than likely.

Comment: That's what `SELECT Count(*)` is for. That's what will get generated if you call `.Count(*)`. If you ask "Can I get the number of results without actually executing the query" the answer is no.

Comment: Yeah, or perhaps more like, "in Sql, does a result know anything about what found it, let alone, as you get it, which OR clause found it? And in just one query. "

Comment: The SQL server does, the result doesn't. You would need to change the query to return a value to help you figure that out.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, but you need to dig more deeper into expression trees.

First, what you need is a dynamic expression like this:

```
(match1 ? 1 : 0) + (match2 ? 1 : 0) + ... + (matchN ? 1 : 0)
```

Then you need to plug it into the selector expression. You can do that in a hard way by manually creating the selector using the `Expression` class methods, or much easier by using what I call prototype expressions. They are compile time lambda expressions with additional parameters which serve as placeholders and later are replaced with other expressions.

In either case you need a helper method for replacing a parameter expression with another expression (for instance to make sure all the `ExpressionMatchList` items use one and the same parameter instance, which is important in EF6). Think of it as expression equivalent of `string.Replace`. There are many examples of how to do that (all based on `ExpressionVisitor`), here is the one I use:

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) =>
            node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Now let implement the aforementioned concept.

First, the prototype expression:

```
Expression<Func<Order, int, OrderInfo>> selectorPrototype = (o, matchCount) => new OrderInfo
{
    // ...
    SearchValue = matchCount,
};
var selectorBody = selectorPrototype.Body;
var selectorParameter = selectorPrototype.Parameters[0];
var matchCountParameter = selectorPrototype.Parameters[1];
```

So it's your original lambda expression selector with additional `matchCount` parameter which we are going to replace with the desired  expression, dynamically built from `ExpressionMatchList`. Let do that:

```
var zero = Expression.Constant(0);
var one = Expression.Constant(1);
var matchCountValue = !ExpressionMatchList.Any() ? zero : ExpressionMatchList
    .Select(match => Expression.Condition(
        match.Body.ReplaceParameter(match.Parameters[0], selectorParameter),
        one, zero))
    .Aggregate<Expression>(Expression.Add);

selectorBody = selectorBody.ReplaceParameter(matchCountParameter, matchCountValue);
```

Now we are ready to create the desired selector:

```
var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<Order, OrderInfo>>(selectorBody, selectorParameter);
```

and use it:

```
var result = context.Orders.Where(expr).Select(selector).ToList();
```

Comment: This is awesome.  It may take me a bit to dig into. I love and am fascinated by how powerful expressions are, so I'll look and update when I have time to do more extensive testing of this.  Thanks!!