# How do I wrap the result of an ExpressionTree in a container class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, expression

I'm trying to create a helper that's compatible with Linq2Sql

The general idea of what I'm trying to do is this:

```cs
internal Expression<Func<TSource, Wrapper<TResult>>>
    Wrap<TSource, TResult>(Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> dataSelector)
    where TSource : IHasOtherProperty
{
    return (TSource data) => new Wrapper<TResult> {
        Entity = dataSelector(data),
        Extra = data.OtherProperty,
    };
}
```

So that I can call:

```
dataStore.Select(Wrap(query))
```

in places that I currently call

```
dataStore.Select(query)
```

Now this needs to be compatible with Linq2Sql, which means it needs to be done as an ExpressionTree.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to allocate the value of dataSelector to the Entity in an EntityFramework friendly manner

Below is the broken prototype:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace TestLinq
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var parent = new ParentDomainModel
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            };

            var test = new TestContext { };
            test.Parents.Add(parent);
            test.Metadata.Add(new MetadataDomainModel { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), IsDeleted = false, Key = "test", Value = "value", Parent = parent });
            test.SaveChanges();

            var result = test.Parents
                .WithMetadata<ParentDomainModel, MetadataDomainModel, ParentApiModel>(d => new ParentApiModel { ID = d.ID });

            var materialized = result
                .ToArray();
        }
    }

    public class ParentApiModel : IDescribedEntity
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<String, String> Metadata { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ParentDomainModel> Parents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MetadataDomainModel> Metadata { get; set; }

        public TestContext() : base()
        {
            this.Database.CommandTimeout = 120;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    public class ParentDomainModel : IDescribedDomainModel<MetadataDomainModel>
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MetadataDomainModel> Metadata { get; set; }
    }

    public class MetadataDomainModel : IMetadata
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public ParentDomainModel Parent { get; set; }
        public Guid ParentID { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public String Key { get; set; }
        public String Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class KeyValuePairApiModel<TKey, TValue>
    {
        [JsonProperty("key")]
        public TKey Key { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public TKey Value { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IDescribedEntity
    {
        IDictionary<String, String> Metadata { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IMetadata
    {
        Guid ParentID { get; set; }

        Boolean IsDeleted { get; set; }

        String Key { get; set; }

        String Value { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IDescribedDomainModel<TMetadata> where TMetadata : IMetadata
    {
        ICollection<TMetadata> Metadata { get; set; }
    }

    public class MetaWrapper<TEntity> where TEntity : IDescribedEntity
    {
        public TEntity Entity { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePairApiModel<String, String>> Metadata { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator TEntity(MetaWrapper<TEntity> data)
        {
            if (data.Metadata != null)
            {
                var metadata = new Dictionary<String, String>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) { };

                foreach (var kvp in data.Metadata)
                {
                    metadata[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
                }

                data.Entity.Metadata = metadata;
            }

            return data.Entity;
        }
    }

    internal static class MetadataHelpers
    {
        internal static IEnumerable<TResult> WithMetadata<TSource, TMetadata, TResult>(
            this IQueryable<TSource> data,
            Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> dataSelector)
            where TMetadata : IMetadata
            where TSource : IDescribedDomainModel<TMetadata>
            where TResult : IDescribedEntity
        {
            var query = data.Select(Wrap<TSource, TMetadata, TResult>(dataSelector));

            return query
                .ToArray()
                .Select(t => (TResult)t);
        }

        internal static Expression<Func<TSource, MetaWrapper<TResult>>> Wrap<TSource, TMetadata, TResult>(
            Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> dataSelector)
            where TMetadata : IMetadata
            where TSource : IDescribedDomainModel<TMetadata>
            where TResult : IDescribedEntity
        {
            var dataParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "data");

            Expression<Func<TSource, IEnumerable<KeyValuePairApiModel<String, String>>>> metaSelector = 
                (d) => d.Metadata == null ? null : d.Metadata
                    .Where(m => !m.IsDeleted)
                    .Select(m => new KeyValuePairApiModel<String, String> { Key = m.Key, Value = m.Value });

            var result = Expression.Variable(typeof(MetaWrapper<TResult>));
            var newWrapper = Expression.Assign(result, Expression.New(typeof(MetaWrapper<TResult>)));
            var entityProperty = Expression.Property(result, nameof(MetaWrapper<TResult>.Entity));
            var assignEntity = Expression.Assign(entityProperty, Expression.Invoke(dataSelector, dataParameter));
            var metaProperty = Expression.Property(result, nameof(MetaWrapper<TResult>.Metadata));
            var assignMetadata = Expression.Assign(metaProperty, Expression.Invoke(metaSelector, dataParameter));


            var block = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, MetaWrapper<TResult>>>(Expression.Block(new [] { dataParameter }, result, newWrapper, assignEntity, assignMetadata, result), dataParameter);

            return block;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block expressions and invocation expressions are not compatible with EF query translator. what you need is [`Expression.MemberInit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.memberinit?view=netframework-4.7.2).

But you can avoid all these complications by using the technique described in [Tracking number of expressions matched before .ToListing an EF Linq Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335666/tracking-number-of-expressions-matched-before-tolisting-an-ef-linq-query/52337670#52337670). Basically you create compile time lambda expression with additional parameters, which are used as placeholders to be replaced with another expression using the following simple helper method:

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) =>
            node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Applying it to your case:

```
internal static Expression<Func<TSource, MetaWrapper<TResult>>> Wrap<TSource, TMetadata, TResult>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> dataSelector)
    where TMetadata : class, IMetadata
    where TSource : class, IDescribedDomainModel<TMetadata>
    where TResult : class, IDescribedEntity
{
    Expression<Func<TSource, TResult, MetaWrapper<TResult>>> template = (source, entity) => new MetaWrapper<TResult>
    {
        Entity = entity,
        Metadata = source.Metadata == null ? null : source.Metadata
            .Where(m => !m.IsDeleted)
            .Select(m => new KeyValuePairApiModel<String, String> { Key = m.Key, Value = m.Value }),
    };
    var sourceParameter = template.Parameters[0];
    var entityParameter = template.Parameters[1];
    var entityValue = dataSelector.Body.ReplaceParameter(dataSelector.Parameters[0], sourceParameter);
    var selectorBody = template.Body.ReplaceParameter(entityParameter, entityValue);
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, MetaWrapper<TResult>>>(selectorBody, sourceParameter);
    return selector;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd established that Block wasn't an option, neither was Invoke. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Still getting NotSupported exceptions though. I'll keep digging!

Comment: It appears that the the Metadata query above is getting a bunch of `Convert` calls added to it.

`{source => new MetaWrapper<ParentApiModel>() {Entity = new ParentApiModel {ID = source.ID, NativeMetadata = source.Metadata.Where(m => Not(m.IsDeleted))}, InjectedMetadata = Convert(source).Metadata.Where(m => Not(Convert(m).IsDeleted)).Select(m => new KeyValuePairApiModel<String, String>() {Key = Convert(m).Key, Value = Convert(m).Value})}}`

Comment: Add `class` constraints in addition to interface constraints, e.g. `where TMetadata : class, IMetadata` and `where TSource : class, IDescribedDomainModel<TMetadata>`. This will remove `Convert`s.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks Ivan, I can stop attempting to unbox manually now.

Comment: After digging around in the EF code, I found the methods that are blocking me from chaining, so have removed my other question. I'll be sticking with this Syntax - thanks again @Ivan Stoev